# Connecting QuickBooks using C#

Tags: c#, quickbooks

when i am trying to connect to quick books using the provided API, i am getting the following error on stack trace

> "Fault Exception of type: AUTHENTICATION has been generated."}

I am using the API's provided by quick books. I have done a dummy set-up on trial site although it does't gives any error while connecting. But while retrieving the data it gives authentication error.

Comment: Are you using the .NET SDK?  https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0

Comment: Post your code so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: when you do this test, are you logged into the QB file as the administrator? the first time any app connects to QB, you have to grant it access, and only the administrator account can do this. Also, have you considered using a third party tool? I use RSSBus for QB integration. It is infinitely easier to work with than the SDK. It even has intellisense from within Visual Studio.